# Pass array to view and display data in PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
 private function displayallsurveys() {
    $this->load->database();
    $sql = "SELECT * from survey";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    $data = array();
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {

       $data = $query->result_array();

       return $data;


    } else {
        return $data;
    }
}
```

Passing to the View

```
    $data = $this->displayallsurveys();
    $this->load->view('SurveyPage', $data);
```

When i show it on the from end

```
<ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Add new Survey</a></li>
       <?php  foreach ($data as $row) {
            $SurveyTitle = $row['SurveyTitle'];
            $SurveyId = $row['SurveyId'];


                  echo'<li id=' . $SurveyId . '><a href=' . $SurveyTitle . '>' . $SurveyTitle . '</a><li>';
       }

          ?>

      </ul>
```

I am getting undefined variable $data

Please someone help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you wanted to use $data variable in the view then you would need to pass it as

```
$this->load->view('SurveyPage', array('data' => $data));
```

Otherwise with the following the array keys becomes the variable names

```
$this->load->view('SurveyPage', $data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass data like this

```
$data['data'] = $this->displayallsurveys();
$this->load->view('SurveyPage', $data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it like:

```
$data['data'] = $this->displayallsurveys();
$this->load->view('SurveyPage', $data);
```

Answer (score 0):

As a practice, it is recommended to use **$data[]** variable as a container of all variables you want to pass to a view. All you just have to do is name the **key** of each.

Example:
$data['survey'] = $this->displayallsurveys();
$this->load->view('SurveyPage', $data);

Then in view :

```
<ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Add new Survey</a></li>
       <?php  foreach ($survey as $row) {
            $SurveyTitle = $row['SurveyTitle'];
            $SurveyId = $row['SurveyId'];


                  echo'<li id=' . $SurveyId . '><a href=' . $SurveyTitle . '>' . $SurveyTitle . '</a><li>';
       }

          ?>

      </ul>
```

Notice :

```
foreach ($survey as $row)
```